# How can I use a cursor, and User-Defined Records and Tables together?

Tags: sql, oracle, cursor, record

I understand how to use cursors, new to the tables and records user-defined types. Not sure how I can incorporate all 3 into a program together.

It can be anything simple that helps me understand how the pieces can work together.

**EDIT**: I should've just used a different website to look for this information, I have since been banned from asking questions because of questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

Look for some examples of wrappering "records" or user defined types so that you can "talk SQL" to them.  Essentially you should be able to expose them as tables or views, then any kind of SQL operations can be performed on them.  Research ...

Comment: Thank you Roger, would I be able to use all 3 at once? Or is it limited to one User-Defined object at a time?

Comment: all at once.  I'm not sure exactly what you mean by record, but I have seen examples of SQL statements aginst user-defined types, so I know that is possible (personally I stay away from types for the most part as when you use scalar data types "life" is much easier and most of the time types are not needed).